# Hyperbolic sine without math.h

Tags: c++, trigonometry

im new to code and c++ for a homework assignment im to create a code for sinh without the math file. I understand the math behind sinh, but i have no idea how to code it, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What math behind it do you understand? Presumably, you have a Taylor series or something like it. A series involves iteratively adding things, which suggests a loop. We can't write your homework for you, but perhaps that will help you get started.

Comment: See "Seminumerical Algorithms" by Knuth.

Comment: Search the internet for "numerical recipes c++".

Comment: Specifically, (and details), what part of the assignment are you having issues with?  **Post your attempt.**

Comment: Step 1:  Write down the steps you would perform when calculating by hand (using pen and paper).  2. Revise the steps if necessary.  3. Convert the steps into C++ code.

Comment: If you would be allowed to use at least pow, I'd propose the exponential definition of the hyperbolic sine, sinh(x) = (e^x - e^-x)/2. Just for the case that you find out that somehow computing exponentials is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia, there is a Taylor series for `sinh`:

```
sinh(x) = x + (pow(x, 3) / 3!) + (pow(x, 5) / 5!) + pow(x, 7) / 7! + ...
```

One challenge is that you are not allowed to use the `pow` function.  The other is calculating the factorial.

The series is a sum of *terms*, so you'll need a loop:

```
double sum = 0.0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_TERMS; ++i)
{
  sum += Term(i);
}
```

You could implement `Term` as a separate function, but you may want to take advantage of declaring and using variables in the loop (that the function may not have access to).

Consider that `pow(x, N)` expands to `x * x * x...`
This means that in each *iteration* the previous value is multiplied by the present value.  (This will come in handy later.)

Consider that `N!` expands to `1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 * ...`
This means that in each *iteration*, the previous value is multiplied by the iteration number.

Let's revisit the loop:

```
double sum = 0.0;
double power = 1.0;
double factorial = 1.0;
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_TERMS; ++i)
{
   // Calculate pow(x, i)
   power = power * x;

   // Calculate x!
   factorial = factorial * i;
}
```

One issue with the above loop is that the `pow` and factorial need to be calculated for each iteration, but the Taylor Series terms use the odd iterations.  This is solved by calculated the terms for odd iterations:

```
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_TERMS; ++i)
{
   // Calculate pow(x, i)
   power = power * x;

   // Calculate x!
   factorial = factorial * i;

   // Calculate sum for odd iterations
   if ((i % 2) == 1)
   {
       // Calculate the term.
       sum += //...
   }
}
```

In summary, the `pow` and factorial functions are broken down into iterative pieces.  The iterative pieces are placed into a loop.  Since the Taylor Series terms are calculated with odd iteration values, a check is placed into the loop.

The actual calculation of the Taylor Series term is left as an exercise for the OP or reader.